# Illinois Legislative Zip to District Match Data Set

Tags: data

I have the Zip +4 for the about 650 areas and I need to find Illinois Senator and Rep code,
address, name. How can I solve this issue. Did anyone solve this issue using any vendor data? We do not want to look up the names of the senators from the website.

Answer (score 1):

The state board of elections says they have shapefiles of the districts that you can get by calling them: [Representative Maps and Descriptions](http://www.elections.il.gov/votinginformation/representativedistricts.aspx)

It doesn't say whether or not you have to purchase the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [2010 Tiger line files](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html) from the US Census to get the districts for the legislators. I'm not sure where you can find free Zip+4 locations but plenty of people sell the data.

Then you can do a simple look up to find which district each zip code is in and then fill in the details of the legislator from which ever source you have (I don't see why you can't look it up on the web site).

Comment: The 2010 TIGER files have the pre-redistricting districts, but if you want the current info, that'd work

Comment: It looks like in 2010 Tiger line file the user must have mapping or Geographic Information System (GIS) software that can import TIGER/Line data. Has anyone worked with the TIGER/Line data. What GIS software did you purchase? Please advice the steps that I need to follow to map the data.

Answer (score 0):

The 2010 TIGER files have the pre-redistricting districts, but if you want the current info, that'd work.  TIGER also has a Zip Code layer which should allow you to district most of the students. http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/main

Look at the Illinois General Assembly site for member info--appears you'll have to do some reformatting to get it into a data format. http://www.ilga.gov/

Answer (score 0):

The [Sunlight Foundation](http://sunlightfoundation.com/) has a lot of legislative [datasets](http://openstates.org/downloads/) nicely packaged together. They provide a dataset for Illinois. This contains non-spatial data. For example, in the file  `legislators.csv` the data is as follows:

```
leg_id,full_name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,suffixes,nickname,active,level,country,state,chamber,district,party,votesmart_id,transparencydata_id,photo_url,created_at,updated_at
ILL000221,Peter J. Roskam,Peter J.,,Roskam,,,False,state,us,il,,,,,,,2011-11-09 09:52:49.992000,2011-11-25 05:14:41.741000
...
```

Comment: Do they really have any geographic data there?  I couldn't find it.

Comment: No, but I thought the question was looking for non-geographic data such as Senator info, etc.

Comment: It is, but it is using ZIP+4 to do it: sounds like a point-in-polygon or similar calculation.  How otherwise do you match the zip codes with congressional district?