# Data attributes in Illinois legislative and senate TIGER shapefile

Tags: shapefile, tiger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Illinois Legislative Zip to District Match Data Set](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/illinois-legislative-zip-to-district-match-data-set)

I have to download illinois legislative and Senate shapefile from [the census bureau](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/main). Do I download State Legislative district from the layer type? Will this file have senator, legislatures name, address and district?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, choose State Legislative Districts as the layer type. You will then be able to download separate shapefiles for the Illinois Upper and Lower Chambers for 2000 & 2010.

These shapefiles do NOT include details about particular politicians, as these boundaries only change during redistricting and therefore each district is often represented by multiple politicians over the course of 10 years. (You may find some additional enlightenment about obtaining that information in the answers to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/illinois-legislative-zip-to-district-match-data-set) question.)